# Сделать первую букву елемента массива заглавной

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

[Код](http://ideone.com/KWUr93)

---

```
    $text = "ну что.      не смотрел еще black mesa.я собирался скачать  ,но все как-то некогда было.";

$regexp = '/[.]/';
$parts = preg_split($regexp, $text, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($parts);

function mb_ucfirst($parts) {
$string = mb_strtoupper(mb_substr($parts, 0, 1)) . mb_substr($parts, 1);
return $string;
}
```

правильно ли я оперирую с $parts, используя его как аргумент для функции? насколько я понимаю, он пропускает каждый елемент массива через функцию?

Comment: [ucfirst](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ucfirst.php)

Comment: это работает для всех кодировок? не нашел в документации ответа

Comment: там на той же странице, есть [коммент](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ucfirst.php#84122) с mb_ucfirst, который емнип работает на utf-8 точно

Comment: Для тех же, для которых работает `strtoupper`. Для utf8 можно использовать `mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
error_reporting(-1);
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
$text = "text. with small. letters.";
print_r (explode(". ",$text));
print_r (ucwords($text));
```

Answer (score 0):

Допустим, что с получением исходного массива у вас проблем не возникает.

```
$source = ['привет', 'мир'];
$result = array_map(function($str) {
  return mb_convert_case($str, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8")
}, $source);
```